# Mongoose Schema enum validation on array of strings

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

The enum validation works when it's a single String:

```
var songSchema = new Schema({
    vocalRange: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Soprano", "Mezzo-soprano", "Contralto", "Alto", "Tenor", "Baritone", "Bass"],
    }
})
```

Trying to POST anything but what's in the enum returns a validation error through mongoose.

However, the following:

```
var songSchema = new Schema({
    vocalRange: {
        type: [String],  // this is what changed
        enum: ["Soprano", "Mezzo-soprano", "Contralto", "Alto", "Tenor", "Baritone", "Bass"],
    }
})
```

Allows me to POST anything for `vocalRange` without any kind of validation. What's going on? And why doesn't the validation work for an array of strings like it does for a single string?

Comment: Have you tried `vocalRange: [{  type: String }]`?

Comment: Oh gosh, I bet that's it. Let me try.

Comment: Yup @tsuz that was it! Thanks, I think I've just had a long day. If you submit that as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering from my comment:

```
vocalRange: [{ type: String }]
```

should work.

Comment: Hey, This is not working for me with latest mongoose@5.6.9

Answer (score -2):

As of `mongoose` version `5.0.6` and higher, the OP issue now works!

```
vocalRange: {
    type: [String],  // this now works!
    enum: ["Soprano", "Mezzo-soprano", "Contralto", "Alto", "Tenor", "Baritone", "Bass"],
}
```

Reference

> https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6204#issuecomment-374690551